# Geometry Question on Quadrilaterals [Triangle and Square]

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle, quadrilateral

[image: Diagram]

Q) ABCD is a square. Prove that Triangle ABP is equilateral

My attempt:as PDC is isosceles, PD = PC, AD = BC and ∠ADP = ∠BCP
therefore, Triangles ADP and BPC are congruent
so BP=AP.. now i don't get how i can get AB=AP=PB

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818611/a-triangle-in-a-square?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case where it's easiest to work backwards. Construct the equilateral triangle $AP'B$. Then triangles $\triangle ADP'$ and $\triangle BP'C$ are obviously isosceles and congruent, with the base angles $\frac{1}{2}(180^\circ-30^\circ)=75^\circ$ each. This leaves $\widehat{P'AB} = \widehat{P'BA}=90^\circ - 75^\circ = 15^\circ$.

It follows that the lines $P'A \equiv PA$ and $P'B \equiv PB$ are in fact identical, since they make the same angles with $AB$. It then follows that their unique intersection must be $P' \equiv P$, so in the end triangle $\triangle APB \equiv \triangle AP'B$ is equilateral.

Comment: well actually i was looking for a way to do it the normal way only.

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "normal". The above is a perfectly good direct proof, and arguably the easiest there is for this problem.

Comment: Like without trignometry

Comment: @Dhruva The proof above uses no trigonometry.